# Register DLL (ActiveX) for Non-Admin user

Tags: dll, activex, windows-installer, registration, non-admin

I try to register dll (ActiveX) for non-admin user using MSI.
To create registry settings I have register the dll in admin mode, then exported the relevant registry entries and renamed all HKLM to HKCU.

When I install it for non-admin user all works fine. But when I use the same settings with admin user, there is a problem of discovering TypeLib.

What should be changed in the registry entries to work both for admin and non-admin user, when the registration done under HKCU?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your entries are really registered under HKCU, it will work.  What MSI installer are you using?  There should be a way to specify that it should install in user mode.

Are you letting the dll self-register or having the msi register the dll?  it is best practice to have the MSI do it, but it's more of a pain.  If you're having the .dll self-register you need to make sure that the dll registers in HKEY_CURRENT_USER and not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which ATL does by default.

If you built it in VS2008 with ATL, you'll want to add:
`AtlSetPerUserRegistration(true);`
to your DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer.

Anyway, those are some things to look for. You can use Process Monitor and watch the Reg commands to see exactly what is happening; something somewhere is writing to HKLM.

Comment: Thank you,
I used MSI installation but there were a problem with importing the registry.

Comment: Does that mean you found the issue?  If so, could you post what it was as an answer?  If not, if you can answer some of the questions that I ask in my answer, I might be able to provide some more insight.